# Should "arguments" be in the reserved words list for identifiers?

Tags: javascript, typescript

[The lists](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f30e8a284ac479a96ac660c94084ce5170543cc4/doc/spec.md#221-reserved-words) of reserved keywords don't include "arguments". Should they? I don't see how "arguments" could be used as an identifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several keyword-like things (or even actual keywords) that aren't reserved words in JavaScript (and thus TypeScript); [details here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words). `arguments` isn't a keyword, it's an implicitly-declared binding (like a variable) within traditional functions (ones using the `function` keyword) and methods (declared with method syntax in classes or object literals). That means you can shadow it, declare it in a context that doesn't already have it, etc.

> I don't see how "arguments" could be used as an identifier.

It can be, but only in loose mode. Here are some examples:

```js
// Arguments isn't implicitly declared outside traditional
// functions and methods
const arguments = 1;
console.log(arguments);     // 1
try {
    arguments = 1.5;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message); // "Assignment to constant variable." (or similar)
}

const fn = () => {
    // Arrow functions don't have an `arguments` identifier declared for them
    let arguments = 2;
    console.log(arguments); // 2
};

fn();

function fn2() {
    if (true) {
        // Shadows the function-wide `arguments` only within this block
        let arguments = 3;
        console.log(arguments); // 3
    }
    // This uses the implicit `arguments` for the function
    console.log(arguments.length); // 0
}

fn2();
```

That's not valid in strict mode, there are restrictions on the use of `arguments` (and `eval`) in strict mode. From the link above:

> The names `arguments` and `eval` are not keywords, but they are subject to some restrictions in strict mode code. See [12.1.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-early-errors), [12.1.3](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-assignmenttargettype), [14.1.2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors), [14.4.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-generator-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors), [14.5.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-async-generator-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors), and [14.7.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors).

Those various linked sections, taken together, basically mean that `arguments` (and `eval`) can't be used as identifiers.

Other keywords or keyword-like things that aren't reserved words:

- `let` and `const` are only keywords just prior to an identifier.
- `async` is only a keyword prior to `function` or prior to a method declaration. Otherwise, it's an acceptable identifier.
- `await` is only a keyword within an `async` function. It's a reserved word in strict mode, but not in loose mode, as are several others.
- `yield` is only a keyword within a generator function. Also reserved in strict mode.
- `NaN`, `undefined`, `Infinity`, and others are read-only properties of the global object, not keywords.
- `import` and `export` are only keywords in modules.

I'm sure that list is incomplete. :-)

This is the nature of an evolving, expanding language that maintains nearly 100% backward compatibility.

Comment: `Infinity` is the same as `NaN`. `let` is a keyword only before an identifier.

Comment: "*that aren't keywords*" probably should read "*that aren't reserved words*"

Comment: @Bergi - True, they had to change the definition of "keyword" for the purposes of the spec when they added contextual ones.

Comment: I get that "arguments" can be used as an identifier in JS and the code you provide does work in JS, but Typescript complains with "Invalid use of 'arguments' in strict mode.(1100)", which makes me think it should be in the list of reserved keywords for identifiers.

Comment: @user3934907 - That's not TypeScript, it's JavaScript's strict mode. That's mentioned by the link above, but I should have called it out in the answer -- I have now. So in strict mode, although they aren't keywords and aren't reserved words, `arguments` and `eval` basically are on a list of things you can't use as identifiers.

Comment: Thanks! How come most of them e.g. await, yield, eval, etc. are in the lists at [1] but arguments is not? [1] https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f30e8a284ac479a96ac660c94084ce5170543cc4/doc/spec.md#2.2.1

Comment: @user3934907 - Looks like a gap in the TS documentation to me. They should mention `arguments` and `eval` like the section of the JS spec I linked above does. They're on a list in the spec (a list of two :-) ).